# Is my code implicitly concurrent?

Tags: scala, concurrency, apache-spark

I have an implementation of `WordCount` that I submit on an `apache-spark` cluster.

I was wondering, **if tasks are launched on executors that have two cores, will they run concurrently on those two cores?**

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280783/concurrency-in-scala), but I'm not sure whether or not I can apply the answer to my case.

```
import org.apache.spark._                                                                                                                                                                                          
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

object WordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount")
    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
    val filename = if (args(0).length > 0) args(0) else "hdfs://x.x.x.x:60070/tortue/wordcount"
    val textFile = spark.textFile(filename)
    val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")) 
                   .map (word => (word, 1)) 
                   .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://x.x.x.x:60070/tortue/wcresults")
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many cores Spark is configured to use on the executors, `spark.executor.cores` is the parameter and its documented in http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html .

Comment: Actually I'm using that parameter to set the executor number of cores. What you're saying is that the task will run concurrently on those two cores if it is alone on the executor?